# Four six-sided dice are rolled. What is the chance that at least one is a 2? What is the chance that the first is a 1 given that at least one is a 2?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So far I have this:

What is the chance that at least one is a 2?

There is $\frac{5}{6}$ that you will not get any 2 on the four dices. From this we get $\frac{5^4}{6^4}$

The probability of getting at least one 2 is $1 - \frac{5^4}{6^4} $

Now I have no idea how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to the first question is correct. For the second question, we use the formula for conditional probability.

Let $A$ be the event that the first die is a $1$.

Let $B$ be the event that at least one is a $2$.

Then,

$$
P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}.
$$

You already concluded that $P(B)=1-\frac{5^{4}}{6^{4}}$. So, we need to find $P(A\cap B)$. Since the first die must be a $1$, one of the next three must be $2$, so, we have $P(A\cap B)=\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\cdot \left(1-\frac{5^{3}}{6^{3}}\right)$.

Hence,

$$
P(A|B)=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\cdot \left(1-\frac{5^{3}}{6^{3}}\right)}{1-\frac{5^{4}}{6^{4}}}=\frac{91}{671}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct for the first part. You just need to simplify your expression to a single fraction.
$\frac{6^4-5^4}{6^4}=\frac{1296-625}{1296}$
$=\frac{671}{1296}$

Comment: Thank you for the help? How do I approach the second part?